# need clarification on JSF and managed beans

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

i have some behavior im unable to understand,
so i started to recently learn JSF, im using TOMCAT 6, now i created JSF file , and i created two Managed Beans under different packages, but each bean have the same name.
 1. First bean is **com.app.TestBean.** 
 2. Second bean is **jsftest.TestBean.**
now when i call my JSF page, i get to invoke the first bean, if i restart the TOMCAT , i get the result of the second bean, can any body explain what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: may i know why you gave -1 for the question ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specified their name explicitely, the beans have their name/id assigned based on they class name.

So TestBean would be: testBean

So if you have conflicting class names, you need to explicitely specify their (different) name.

For example if you are using the annotation (which i suspect is the case), you need to do

```
package com.app;

@ManagedBean("testBean1")
public class TestBean {
  ...
}
```

and the other bean

```
package jsftest;

@ManagedBean("testBean2")
public class TestBean {
  ...
}
```

And then use either #{testBean1} or #{testBean2}

Comment: i know about this approach, but i was hoping to get explanation on why is this happening ? why JSF does not consider the package name.

Comment: No it doesn't, it only uses the class name, so if multiple classes have the same class name, they will conflict